# Создание нескольких словарей из списка в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать Python и в одном из заданий столкнулся с задачей, решения которой найти пока не смог.

Суть вопроса в следующем:
Есть список данных

```
list = ('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')
```

Необходимо создать словари с названиями из этого списка.

Пытался создавать список в цикле:

```
for animal in list:
    animal = {}
```

Но список принимает имя animal вместо имени переменной (в принципе логично, но как сделать иначе - пока не понимаю).

ай нид хэлп (поиском искал, но не нашёл).

---

Пардон, в изначальной формулировке был не точен.
Далее я хочу эти словари заполнить свойствами животных. Опустил это действие, т.к. пока до него не могу дойти. Если всё же в исходных данных использовать список, решение сильно поменяется?

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']

    for animal in animals:
    # тут я хочу создать словарь с именем животного
    # тут я хочу внести в словарь индекс 'name' и в значение - имя животного

# на выходе хочу получить
print(dog) # {'name': 'dog'}
print(cat) # {'name': 'cat'}
print(mouse) # {'name': 'mouse'}
```

Comment: У вас там не список, а кортеж (tuple), они похожи, но разные, и не используйте ключевые слова. `list` -- это встроенная функция для создания списков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. вы не описывали что хотите делать с словарем, то приведу свой пример:

```
animals = ('dog', 'cat', 'mouse')

# Не знаю что вы там хотите сделать со словарем, пусть будет в нем
# количество животных
animal_by_number = dict()

for animal in animals:
    animal_by_number[animal] = 0

# Вместо тех 3 строк (объявление и цикл) можно использовать генератор:
# animal_by_number = {animal : 0 for animal in animals}

animal_by_number['dog'] = 10
animal_by_number['cat'] = 5

print(animal_by_number)  # {'cat': 5, 'dog': 10, 'mouse': 0}
```

---

Согласно уточнению автора:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']

dog = cat = mouse = None

for animal in animals:
    if animal == 'dog':
        dog = {'name': animal}
    elif animal == 'cat':
        cat = {'name': animal}
    elif animal == 'mouse':
        mouse = {'name': animal}

print(dog)  # {'name': 'dog'}
print(cat)  # {'name': 'cat'}
print(mouse)  # {'name': 'mouse'}
```

Но лучше бы сделать так:

```
# Список, обращение идет по индексам
animals_obj_list = [{'name': animal} for animal in animals]

# Словарь, обращение идет по ключу -- имени животному
animals_obj_dict = {animal: {'name': animal} for animal in animals}

print(animals_obj_list)  # [{'name': 'dog'}, {'name': 'cat'}, {'name': 'mouse'}]
print(animals_obj_list[0])  # {'name': 'dog'}
print()
print(animals_obj_dict)  # {'dog': {'name': 'dog'}, 'cat': {'name': 'cat'}, 'mouse': {'name': 'mouse'}}
print(animals_obj_dict['dog'])  # {'name': 'dog'}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь стало понятно!

Answer (score 1):

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
animals_property = ['age', 'delicious']

animal_dict = {animal: {}.fromkeys(animals_property) for animal in animals}
print(animal_dict)
# {'dog': {'delicious': None, 'age': None}, 'mouse': {'delicious': None, 'age': None}, 'cat': {'delicious': None, 'age': None}}

mouse = animal_dict['mouse']
mouse['delicious'] = 'YES!'
mouse['age'] = 1
print(mouse)
# {'age': 1, 'delicious': 'YES!'}
```

Comment: Интересно выглядит :)